# RSpec suite performance difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I've got an interesting problem that's causing myself and my team a lot of headaches when it comes to running our spec suite.

Our spec suite is broken up into the following sub-folders, and next to them is their total execution time to completion:

```
rspec spec/acceptance    311.67s
rspec spec/controllers   18.97s
rspec spec/decorators    4.39s
rspec spec/helpers       9.45s
rspec spec/lib           16.88s
rspec spec/mailers       5.27s
rspec spec/models        121.05s
rspec spec/presenters    0.03s
rspec spec/workers       19.3s

Total run time: 8m 27s
```

Which certainly could be improved, but all in all is pretty managable.

However, if, I run `rspec spec` and run the entire suite at once, the total time to complete is `27m 11s`!

So, obviously something we are doing is dramatically affecting the performance of the entire suite when run at once.  I'm hoping that I can get some pointers as to where I can begin to try to troubleshoot this problem.

If it helps, I've posted my `spec_helper.rb` file [here](https://gist.github.com/thedelchop/5541750)

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: Have you run a profiler against `rspec spec`? With the drastic difference in times I would think the heavy consumers would jump out. Something like [`perftools.rb`](https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb) which supports method call graphs could be helpful.

Comment: What does profiling tell you? Run `rspec spec --profile` or add `--profile` to your `~/.rspec` file. It will show you the 10 slowest tests.

Comment: Ok that is what I will do to start.

Comment: Adding my comment as an answer, if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say your integration specs are setting `DatabaseCleaner` to `:truncation` and it's not getting switched back to `:transaction` for the other specs. I have a sample `spec_helper` that navigates the situation [here](https://gist.github.com/mockdeep/9904695). There are also a couple methods provided that help you dig in and figure out which strategy is being used at any given time. Here it is for your convenience:

```
def cleaner_strategy
  active_record_cleaner.instance_variable_get(:@strategy).class
end

def active_record_cleaner
  DatabaseCleaner.instance_variable_get(:@cleaners)[[:active_record, {}]]
end
```

Side note: we use a filter for our integration specs since they are so slow. We disable them by default in our local env, and then let CI run them.

```
config.filter_run_excluding :slow unless ENV['SLOW']
```

Then you can run them individually with:

```
$ SLOW=true rspec spec/features/some_awesome_feature_spec.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

What does profiling tell you?

Run `rspec spec --profile` or add `--profile` to your `~/.rspec` file.

On completion of your tests, it will report the 10 slowest tests.